# Mathematica clear a function's derivative definition

Tags: function, wolfram-mathematica, derivative

I defined the derivative of a function in Mathematica without defining the function itself, i.e. I have a function definition that looks like this:

```
y'[x_] := constant * f'[x].
```

I can't figure out how to clear it out. If I use `Clear[y']` or `ClearAll[y'], I get an error message:

> `ClearAll::ssym: y'` is not a symbol or a string.

`Clear[y]` and `ClearAll[y]` do nothing to remove the definition of `y'`.

Any ideas on how I can remove the definition of `y'`?

Answer (score 5):

This should do what you want:

```
y'[x_] =.
```

See [`Unset`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Unset.html).  Also see [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/373/121) for related information.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Remove[y]`.  For a function name `f'` is unusual syntax, but it does appear in the documentation for derivative: http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Derivative.html

The derivative name form seems to present a bit of a problem for `Information (??)`, which would usually show attribute information.

```
y'[x_] := constant*f'[x]
y'[4]
??y
```

constant f'[4]

Global`y

```
Remove[y]
??y
```

Information::notfound :  Symbol y not found. >>

```
y'[4]
```

y'[4]

But oddly, (and nothing to do with the derivative name form):

```
Information[y]
```

Global`y

There is some deeper information about `Remove` here: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/4921/what-is-the-story-with-removed-symbols