# Mathematica Euler's Method

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I am trying to solve a differential equation in Mathematica, and I don't really understand it very well. I will show the equation, my attempt and the error message below:

equation:

```
dp(t)/dt=rb(1-p(t))
```

attempt:

```
b = .02;
d = .015;
r = .1;
h = 1;
t = 0;
Clear[p, t]
DSolve[{p'[t] == r*b*(1 - p[t]), p[0] == .01}, p[t], t]
```

Error:

```
DSolve::deqn: Equation or list of equations expected instead of True in the first     argument {True,p[0]==0.01}. >>
```

Comment: Your code works for me, you just defined p or p' before, and have to clear it. I have no idea how, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12454887/mathematica-clear-a-functions-derivative-definition and this doesn't help. Try to change t variable, or close mathematica and reload your workbook.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot set `t=0` because then it is a number. On a session the following gives

```
b = 2/100;
d = 15/1000;
r = 1/10;
h = 1;

DSolve[{p'[t] == r*b*(1 - p[t]), p[0] == .01}, p[t], t]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]